# Error when starting Rails Server after ruby upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was using Ruby 2.2 and Rails 4.2.0 and everything was working fine
But since upgrading Ruby to 2.4.0, I'm getting the error message below.  I have also tried it with Ruby 2.6.5.  Same thing.  Please Help!

```
rails s
/Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/roxml-3.3.1/lib/roxml/definition.rb:156: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
   ... 4818 levels...
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/varunaggarwal/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Rails 4.2.0 is completely unpatched. At least use 4.2.11.1 which is the latest in the 4.2.x series.

Answer (score 2):

I read here (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27670) that Ruby 2.4 requires Rails 4.2.8 or higher.  Upgrading rails from 4.2.0 to 4.2.8 solved it.

in gemfile, I changed gem 'rails', '4.2.0' to gem 'rails', '4.2.8'

Comment: Don't forget to get some kind of vulnerability alerting on your projects as keeping this at 4.2.0 for so long should have set off alarm bells. There's been several significant security fixes released since that initial version.